# How to access an element in array vector using metaprogramming?

Tags: arraylist, metaprogramming, dynamic-sql, dolphindb

Here is a table `t`. The data form of column `arr1` is array vector.

```
arr1=array(DOUBLE[], 0, 10).append!([2 3 4, 4 5 7, 7 9 10])
t = table(1..3 as id, arr1, rand(100, 3) as value)
```

I can use a SQL statement to query for the first element in column `arr1`, i.e., arr1[0].

```
select arr1[0] from t
```

Output:

```
arr1_at
2
4
7
```

Now I want to query using metaprogramming.

```
sql(select = sqlCol('arr1[0]') ,from =t).eval()
```

But an error was raised as follows:

```
Server response: 'Unrecognized column name arr1[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following two lines:

```
sql(select=sqlColAlias(<arr1[0]>,"arr1_0"), from=t).eval()


sql(select=sqlColAlias(makeCall(at, sqlCol("arr1"), 0), "arr1_0"), from=t).eval()
```

Output:

```
arr1_0
2
4
7
```

The first line uses the metacode <arr1[0]>.

The second line uses function `makeCall` to call the `at` function to get the value at the 0-th position in column `arr1` and thus obtain the new column `arr1_0`.